# Querying large database using read.odbc.ffdf exhausts memory in R

Tags: r, memory-management, rodbc

I'm trying to query a large database and then save the returned result as an ff object using the read.odbc.ffdf function. The following code should allow me to pull in a thousand rows at a time, save the data as an ff object, and then move onto the next thousand rows, appending these to the previous file, so that I can preserve memory:

```
library(ff);
library(ffbase);
library(ETLUtils);
library(RODBC);

sqlcode <- "SELECT f.*
FROM table1 AS f;";

data <-read.odbc.ffdf(query = sqlcode,
odbcConnect.arg = list('data1; db=research'),
nrows = 1000,
next.rows = 1000,
BATCHBYTES = 100000;
dim(data);
```

However, when I do this, R eventually eats up all my RAM, and eventually the process terminates before the object "data" is completely filled. Inspecting "data" reveals the following error message:

```
read.odbc.ffdf 1.. ()  odbc-read=822.06secError in if (nrow(dat) == 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

Any ideas what this error message means? How can I query this database without exhausting my memory (4 GB RAM)? I expect the option "BATCHBYTES" in combination with "first.rows" and "next.rows" to keep my memory usage low (within 100,000 bytes, which should be enough for my system).

Am I just not understanding how function read.odbc.ffdf works with the first.rows, next.rows, and BATCHBYTES options?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly specified odbcConnect.arg. odbcConnect needs dsn, uid and pwd? You supplied none of them. read.odbc.ffdf is basically a wrapper around odbc functionality to directly import data in an ffdf. Have you tried out doing the steps by hand to connect to your DB (odbcConnect, odbcQuery and sqlGetResults) possibly with a smaller query to see if that worked?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do believe the odbcConnect.arg is correctly specified. I rechecked it using the following query:
    con = odbcConnect('data1; db=research');
    sqlQuery(con, "select count(id) FROM Table1");
I believe it works because the odbcConnect argument accesses stored information in MySQL Workbench. I'm assuming that applying this same information in the odbcConnect.arg argument in the read.odbc.ffdf function will give the same result? While I can't be sure, usually when the connection is mis-specified, my computer doesn't use RAM, but in this case, it eats through it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with odbcQuery versus sqlQuery? Replacing the above sqlQuery command with odbcQuery returns "1", which is not correct.

Comment: Your problem is with the connection settings not with RAM as you didn't retrieve any data from your database. If your dsn is correct as you indicated, you need to supply odbcConnect.arg = list(dsn='data1; db=research') and not odbcConnect.arg = list('data1; db=research'). You might want to start with sqlcode <- "select * from table1 limit 10000" to see if your connection specification is working.

Comment: I wasn't able to run it using that command, but I did get it to work using a different procedure documented here: [link](http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/19-get-your-large-sql-data-in-ff-swiftly).

Comment: Even better. Using read.dbi.ffdf is mostly better as it uses DBI instead of ODBC and for your MySQL DB, this means it uses the native MySQL drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful responses!